I want to use Month Name rather than Month Number in my slicer
I have a combined table of data from every month of the year. I am trying to visualize the change in balance of a single Investor over a month. My table includes a Month Name column and a Month Number column.
I have the folllowing DAX measure that runs correctly when I use Monrh Number in the slider but if I use Month Name is the slider my code does not retrieve the previous month's balance.
Change2 = 
VAR CurrentMonthNumber = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(CombinedTables[Month Number]),  -- Get the Month Number
        CombinedTables[Month Name] = SELECTEDVALUE(CombinedTables[Month Name])  -- Match the selected Month Name
    )
VAR PrevMonthNumber = 
    IF(
        CurrentMonthNumber = 1,  -- Handle January explicitly
        BLANK(),
        CurrentMonthNumber - 1
    )
VAR Result = 
    SUMX(
        DISTINCT(CombinedTables[Investor NIN]),  -- Iterate over each unique Investor NIN
        VAR CurrentInvestorNIN = [Investor NIN]  -- Store the current Investor NIN being processed
        VAR CurrentBalance = 
            CALCULATE(
                SUM(CombinedTables[Current Balance]),  -- Get Current Balance for Current Month
                CombinedTables[Month Number] = CurrentMonthNumber,  -- Filter for Current Month
                CombinedTables[Investor NIN] = CurrentInvestorNIN  -- Scope to the current Investor NIN
            )
        VAR PreviousBalance = 
            CALCULATE(
                SUM(CombinedTables[Current Balance]),  -- Get Current Balance for Previous Month
                CombinedTables[Month Number] = PrevMonthNumber,  -- Filter for Previous Month
                CombinedTables[Investor NIN] = CurrentInvestorNIN  -- Scope to the same Investor NIN in the previous month
            )
        RETURN 
            IF(
                ISBLANK(CurrentBalance) || ISBLANK(PreviousBalance),
                BLANK(),
                CurrentBalance - PreviousBalance  -- Subtract Previous Month Balance from Current Month Balance
            )
    )
RETURN
    Result  -- Final return statement


I have tried rewritting and debugging the previous month number calculation multiple times to no avail. I also hard coded the previous month number but it still doesn't give me the previous balance unless I use Month Number is the slicer
